# how to change/customize minicart dropdrow instead a dropdown cart I wish having a slider from right do left at magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, magento2minicart

how to change/customize minicart dropdrow... instead a dropdown cart I wish having a slider from right do left at magento 2.4.4
could someone help me ? Also please suggest me if any extension is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this behavior with minicart template

**app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml**

```html
<!-- ... -->
<div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "show":{"effect":"slide","direction":"right"},
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": false,
                "closeOnClickOutside": false,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
<!-- ... -->
```

See part `"show":{"effect":"slide","direction":"right"},`

Comment: Sorry for being late..
This didn't work for me ;/ so I made it with css

Answer (score 0):

Below is the extension which can help you

Magento: https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-slidingcart.html

Github: https://github.com/ambab-infotech/slidingcart